# What is a description?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

I am a physicist/mathematician working on reduction of description. In my case the meaning of description is:

A representation of some perceived phenomenon into a (formal) language.

Are there any other accounts of "description"? Any debate? Any attempts defining what a "description" is?

Comment: I think if you are not narrowing the scope of the question to at least reference requests for some named philosophers/philosophical schools, this one will be closed due to being too broad or asking for a definition of a term. There in fact have been plenty definitions of this term throughout the history of philosophy.

Comment: @Marlo As Philip points out the issue of *description* is a broad field. To start with see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descriptions/#WhaDes

Comment: Its kind of a shame that definition questions have to be off topic.  While I understand why they are a poor fit for SE, this is a good philosophy question... just maybe not a good one for the site.  It can be frustrating when people blindly assume their meaning for a fundamental word, like "description," must be universal, and quite refreshing to see someone questioning it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try to rephrase the question. Its my first post on the philosophy stackexchange, so I will try to adopt the appropriate question style. Thanks @CortAmmon for your encouraging words.